# Passing date to request param in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am new to Spring MVC - and I am trying to pass a date from my javascript as a request Param

My controller looks something like -

```
public @ResponseBody List<RecordDisplay> getRecords(
            @RequestParam(value="userID") Long userID,
            @RequestParam(value="fromDate") Date fromDate,
            @RequestParam(value="toDate") Date toDate) {
```

The question I have is how do I make the call from javascript - as in what should the URL look like

```
for eg. - /getRecords?userID=1&fromDate=06022013&toDate=08022013'
```

Do I need a way to parse the date so Spring can recognize it?

Comment: Can you share the code you have used to compare two dates?

Answer (score 109, accepted):

Use `@DateTimeFormat("MMddyyyy")`

```
public @ResponseBody List<RecordDisplay> getRecords(
@RequestParam(value="userID")  Long userID,
@RequestParam(value="fromDate")     @DateTimeFormat(pattern="MMddyyyy") Date fromDate,
@RequestParam(value="toDate")     @DateTimeFormat(pattern="MMddyyyy") Date toDate) {
```

Comment: is @DateFormat from spring?

Comment: I couldn't find `@Dateformat` in spring, but I did find `@DateTimeFormat` like @dannrob says.

Comment: Oh, and this has bitten me before `"mm"` in java date time formats is MINUTES and `"MM"` is MONTHS.

Comment: +1 for Jim.. Also couldn't find `@DateFormat`, but `@DateTimeFormat`.

Comment: FWIW, I had to add `@DateTimeFormat(pattern="MMddyyyy")`.  Answer given [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15164985/777980)

Answer (score 28):

This is now @DateTimeFormat as well which supports some common ISO formats

Comment: Yes! Complementing this answer: It does looks much better like this: @RequestParam(value = "onDate") @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE) LocalDate onDate,

Answer (score 11):

Use @DateTimeFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd") where yyyy is year, MM is month and dd is date

```
public @ResponseBody List<Student> loadStudents(@DateTimeFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd") Date birthDay) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: @DateTimeFormat was valid for me as an option, but I had to also specifically add the pattern attribute to the annotation

Comment: Better to use `@DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE)`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use your `application.properties` (or any other project properties) and set the environment variable `spring.mvc.format.date`.