# How to accept Date params in a GET request to Spring MVC Controller?

Tags: java, spring, date, spring-mvc

I've a GET request that sends a date in YYYY-MM-DD format to a Spring Controller.
The controller code is as follows:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/fetch" , method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody String fetchResult(@RequestParam("from") Date fromDate) {
        //Content goes here
    }
```

The request is sent correctly as I'm checking with Firebug.
I get the error:

> HTTP Status 400: The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.

How can I make the controller accept this format of Date? 
Please help. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I guess your Date is from java.util.Date because provided answers so not work with Java.sql.Date

Answer (score 291, accepted):

Ok, I solved it.
Writing it for anyone who might be tired after a full day of non-stop coding & miss such a silly thing.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/fetch" , method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody String fetchResult(@RequestParam("from") @DateTimeFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd") Date fromDate) {
        //Content goes here
    }
```

Yes, it's simple. Just add the DateTimeFormat annotation.

Comment: I was going to write an answer but you beat me. You can also use @DateTimeFormat(iso=ISO.DATE), which is the same format. BTW, if you can I suggest that you use the Joda DateTime library. Spring supports it really well.

Comment: The answer is generally ok, BUT! Is there a way to configure it as a default to Spring? It's a little bit overkill to put `@DateTimeFormat` in every controller you have...

Comment: @Luciano of course you can do @DateTimeFormat(iso = ISO.DATE_TIME) as well

Comment: @thorinkor In Spring Boot you can set the `spring.mvc.date-format` attribute in `application.properties` or add beans that implement the `org.springframework.format` interface (extending `org.springframework.format.datetime.DateFormatter` is probably the way to go). In non-Boot Spring you can `@Override` the `addFormatters` method of `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` and add your Formatter-implementing beans there.

Comment: People should be aware that :@DateTimeFormat' does not work with 'java.sql.Date' but with 'java.util' dates

Answer (score 15):

... or you can do it the right way and have a coherent rule for serialisation/deserialisation of dates all across your application. put this in application.properties:

```
spring.mvc.date-format=yyyy-MM-dd
```

Comment: It doesn't work, tried it using pattern, iso, sane issue, cannot convert string to date

Comment: Btw, are you using java.util.Date or kava.sql.Date?  This is not working with Java.sql.Date

Answer (score 14):

This is what I did to get formatted date from front end

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/{dateString}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  @ResponseBody
  public HttpStatus getSomething(@PathVariable @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE) String dateString) {
   return OK;
  }
```

You can use it to get what you want.

Comment: Didn't get it. What's the point of adding @​DateTimeFormat to @​PathVariable if you receive dateString as String, not as Date?

Answer (score 8):

Below solution perfectly works for spring boot application.

**Controller:**

```
@GetMapping("user/getAllInactiveUsers")
List<User> getAllInactiveUsers(@RequestParam("date") @DateTimeFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") Date dateTime) {
    return userRepository.getAllInactiveUsers(dateTime);
}
```

So in the caller (in my case its a web flux), we need to pass date time in this(**"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"**) format.

**Caller Side:**

```
public Flux<UserDto> getAllInactiveUsers(String dateTime) {
    Flux<UserDto> userDto = RegistryDBService.getDbWebClient(dbServiceUrl).get()
            .uri("/user/getAllInactiveUsers?date={dateTime}", dateTime).retrieve()
            .bodyToFlux(User.class).map(UserDto::of);
    return userDto;
}
```

**Repository:**

```
@Query("SELECT u from User u  where u.validLoginDate < ?1 AND u.invalidLoginDate < ?1 and u.status!='LOCKED'")
List<User> getAllInactiveUsers(Date dateTime);
```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use a PathVariable, you can use an example method below (all methods are and do the same):

```
//You can consume the path .../users/added-since1/2019-04-25
@GetMapping("/users/added-since1/{since}")
public String userAddedSince1(@PathVariable("since") @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd") Date since) {
    return "Date: " + since.toString(); //The output is "Date: Thu Apr 25 00:00:00 COT 2019"
}

//You can consume the path .../users/added-since2/2019-04-25
@RequestMapping("/users/added-since2/{since}")
public String userAddedSince2(@PathVariable("since") @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE) Date since) {
    return "Date: " + since.toString(); //The output is "Date: Wed Apr 24 19:00:00 COT 2019"
}

//You can consume the path .../users/added-since3/2019-04-25
@RequestMapping("/users/added-since3/{since}")
public String userAddedSince3(@PathVariable("since") @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd") Date since) {
    return "Date: " + since.toString(); //The output is "Date: Thu Apr 25 00:00:00 COT 2019"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use :

public @ResponseBody String fetchResult(**@RequestParam("from")@DateTimeFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd")** Date fromDate) {
//Your code...

```
}
```

Answer (score 1):

2000-10-31T01:30:00.000-05:00  convert to Datetime (Joda)

```
@GetMapping("test/{dateTimeStart}")
public void getCheckDaily2(
        @PathVariable(value = "dateTimeStart", required = false)
            @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME)
                DateTime dateTimeStart){

body here...
}
```