# Spring MVC controller with date

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I've been trying to use:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/consultaporusuarioperiodo/{idusuario}/{datainicio}/{datafim}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String consultaPorPeriodoUsuario(
        @PathVariable("idusuario") Long idUsuario,
        @PathVariable("datainicio") Date dataInicio,
        @PathVariable("datafim") Date dataFim
        ,Model model) {
    Usuario usuario = usuarioService.buscaPorId(idUsuario);
    model.addAttribute("timesheet",timeSheetService.buscaPorPeriodoPorUsuario(dataInicio, dataFim,usuario));
    return "timesheetcrud/consultatimesheet";
}
```

with this link:

```
http://localhost:8080/timesheet/consultaporusuarioperiodo/1/21012000/22012000
```

but I get this error:

```
HTTP Status 400 -

type Status report

message

description The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect ().

Apache Tomcat/7.0.27
```

when I change to:

```
        @PathVariable("datainicio") String dataInicio,
        @PathVariable("datafim") String dataFim
```

It's work. What can I do to work with Date ?

thanks

Comment: Try annotating your date parameters with `@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "ddMMyyyy")`

Comment: I've already tried with @DateTimeFormat but when I put @PathVariable("datainicio") @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "ddMMyyyy") Date dataInicio, It's not work too :-( Only work with String.

Comment: Tip: Try to use best practices and pass this two date values in Request Body or Query Parameters. http://apigee.com/about/api-best-practices =)

Comment: Mark the answer as correct to help the community :) Also its duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15164864/how-to-accept-date-params-in-a-get-request-to-spring-mvc-controller

Answer (score 23):

Try:

```
    @PathVariable("datainicio") @DateTimeFormat(iso=ISO.DATE) String dataInicio,
    @PathVariable("datafim") @DateTimeFormat(iso=ISO.DATE) String dataFim
```

where `ISO.DATE` is of `yyyy-mm-dd` pattern.

Answer (score 11):

I had to do something very similar. This is what I did:

```
@PathVariable("datainicio") @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "ddMMyyyy") Date dataInicio
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

In Spring's spirit, the best choice should be a convention to impose a unified way of handling Date parameters. And luckily it gives you exactly this little cookie - drop it in application.properties and ... Bob's your uncle:

> spring.mvc.date-format=ddMMyyyy