# how to pass date via url parameter - junit test with dates

Tags: java, junit, controller, url-parameters

I want to pass my Date via parameter, and I dont exactly know how to do it. I have tried EncodeUrl.encode(), but it didnt work (it is possible that I did something wrong)

```
@Test
public void getUsageCountersParam2Test() throws Exception {
    Date date = new Date(2017, 06, 23, 12, 39, 20);
    MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(get(getUri("/usages?apiConsumerId=[1,2]&serviceId=1&dateFrom=" + date)).contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)).andExpect(status().isOk()).andReturn();
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    List<UsageCounterDetailsDto> list = mapper.readValue(result.getResponse().getContentAsString(), new TypeReference<List<UsageCounterDetailsDto>>() {
    });

    assertNotNull(list);
    assertEquals(3, list.size());
}
```

I have an error such as:

```
org.springframework.web.method.annotation.MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.Date'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam java.util.Date] for value 'Mon Jul 23 12:39:20 CEST 3917'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
```

Hope you could helped me.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15164864/how-to-accept-date-params-in-a-get-request-to-spring-mvc-controller) might help.

Comment: But in that particular case you are assuming that I should modify controller not only test as I primaly want. At the moment Date and Timestamp from DB should be adjusted to each other.

If I wouldnt gain any more answers then I will try this one (or if my case turn out to be incorrect)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'Z", Locale.ENGLISH);
    String dateParam = sdf.format(date);
    MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(get("/usages")
            .param("date", dateParam))
            .andExpect(status().isOk()).andReturn();
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue and found that adding the @DateTimeFormat annotation to my controller helped.

Helpful Links:
[How to accept Date params in a GET request to Spring MVC Controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15164864/how-to-accept-date-params-in-a-get-request-to-spring-mvc-controller)

[Spring MVC controller with date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16846763/spring-mvc-controller-with-date)

https://codingexplained.com/coding/java/spring-framework/date-parameter-in-spring-mvc-controller

Answer (score 0):

You can use @InitBinder annotation to allow controller to accept different date formats.

[here is a one nice example](http://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-web-mvc/spring-custom-property-editor/)