# How do I make a spring-boot request method accept an iso formatted date param?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, datetime, spring-boot, isodate

I'm trying to write a controller request method that accepts a date parameter that is sent as an iso formatted date time string. [It looks like you can specify a format manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15164864/how-to-accept-date-params-in-a-get-request-to-spring-mvc-controller/15164985#15164985), annotating the method parameter with `@DateTimeFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd")` but I want to use the `iso`
 setting. I.e. `@DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME)`. Using the ISO Date Time format I can't even get it to parse the example date in the documentation. I'm wondering if I'm doing something wrong.

Here is my controller class:

```
@RestController
public class DateController {

    @RequestMapping(path = "/echoIsoDate", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<String> echoIsoDate(@RequestParam("date") @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME) Date date){
        return new ResponseEntity<>(date.toString(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @RequestMapping(path = "/echoDumbDate", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<String> echoDumbDate(@RequestParam("date") @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd") Date date){
        return new ResponseEntity<>(date.toString(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

When I try to call this controller with the date I actually want to parse it doesn't work:

```
http://localhost:8080/echoIsoDate?date=2015-12-30T00:00:00.000Z
```

When I try to call this controller [with the example date from the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/format/annotation/DateTimeFormat.ISO.html#DATE_TIME) it doesn't work:

```
http://localhost:8080/echoIsoDate?date=2000-10-31%2001:30:00.000-05:00
```

The second controller method does work. e.g calling `http://localhost:8080/echoDumbDate?date=1970-01-01` returns `Thu Jan 01 00:00:00 CST 1970` (But then it's in CST, which presumably is in my system timezone).

Questions:

- What am I doing wrong in `echoIsoDate()`? Or is there a bug in Spring?
- For `echoDumbDate()` is there a way to specify the timezone I want, so that it will always use UTC?

Answer (score 1):

try this instead

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/echoIsoDate", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<String> echoIsoDate(@RequestParam("date") @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'") Date date){
    return new ResponseEntity<>(date.toString(), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```