# How to accept LocalDateTime param in a GET request to Spring Boot Controller?

Tags: java, spring

This question is very similar to [this SO problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15164864/3913366) which is for older `Date` API.

I want to achieve the same with Java 8 `LocalDateTime` API. When I do,

```
@RequestMapping("/locationSnapshot/{userId}/{pointInTime}")
public MyResponse getLocationInTime(
        @PathParam(value="userId") Long userId,
        @PathParam(value="pointInTime")
        @DateTimeFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss") LocalDateTime pointInTime) {

    MyResponse response = new MyResponse();
    return response;
}
```

I get,

```
Failed to instantiate [java.time.LocalDateTime]: No default constructor
found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: 
java.time.LocalDateTime.<init>()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use @PathVariable instead of @PathParam

```
@RequestMapping("/locationSnapshot/{userId}/{pointInTime}")
public MyResponse getLocationInTime(
        @PathVariable(value="userId") Long userId,
        @PathVariable(value="pointInTime")
        @DateTimeFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss") LocalDateTime pointInTime) {

    MyResponse response = new MyResponse();
    return response;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to add `@RequestParam` before your `pointInTime` parameter.

Comment: While I get this and it is **working correctly** with `@RequestParam`. But according to OP, I want it to work as a `@PathParam`. Any ideas on that?

Comment: `@PathParam` belongs to `javax.ws.rs` package, if you intent on using spring for developing REST web service, you should use `@RequestParam` (or any other spring annotation). Using `@PathParam` should be preffered if you use jetty.

Comment: @ShubhamA. ok, i'm not sure, but what if try to `@PathVariable`?