# it is possible to find data according to date in spring

Tags: java, spring, date, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I'm trying to find data according to date throw the exception

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: null

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @GetMapping("/product-DateList/{pathDate}")
    public ModelAndView getFindByDateOfPurchase(@PathVariable("pathDate") String pathDate) {
        Date convertDate = new Date(pathDate);
        //Date Converted according to dataBase Format 
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        String strDate = sdf.format(convertDate);
        Date date = null; 
        try {
            date =   DateFormat.getInstance().parse(strDate);
        } catch (ParseException pe) {
            pe.printStackTrace();
        }

        List<Product> dateofPurchaseList = grofersService.findByDateOfPurchase(date);

        Optional<List<Product>> optional = Optional.of(dateofPurchaseList);
        if (!optional.isPresent()) {
            logger.warn("Not Found Product");
            return new ModelAndView("notFound"); 
        }
        logger.info("Fetching Product according to Date");
        return new ModelAndView("productList", "dateofPurchaseList", dateofPurchaseList); 
    }
```

Exception (PrintStacktrace)

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: null
    at java.util.Date.parse(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
    at java.util.Date.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
    at com.javabootstar.controller.GrofersController.getFindByDateOfPurchase(GrofersController.java:66) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133) ~[spring-web-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_172]
```

search this problem in google does not find this type of problem, how to find data according to date.

Comment: Please post the whole stacktrace.

Comment: Can you share entire stacktrace?

Comment: okay i will share.

Comment: In `GrofersController.java` line 66 you do something with a date that is `null`.

Comment: but how to find data according to date.

Comment: You can configure the controller method to parse automatically the argument into a date. You can check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15164985/3921725

Comment: And point us what's on line 66. Add a print statement or run the debugger and check what's going on there. Also, what are you exactly doing with the `pathDate`? It's unused in your code.

Comment: this link is very helpful but one doubt . I'm using PathVariable annotation then throw the exception. @AlexRoig

Comment: Since you can use Java 8 (or higher, for example`Optional` (and even if you could not)), you should shun the old classes `Date`, `SimpleDateFormat` and `DateFormat` since they are poorly designed, troublesome and also long outdated. [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) is so much nicer to work with.

Comment: @PathVariable("pathDate") @DateTimeFormat(iso=ISO.DATE) Date dateReceived) it possible to use but i'm use this statement throw Exception parseException @Alex Roig

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems with the code you have posted, more importantly that this would not compile.

`Date convertDate = new Date` - This is obvsiously wrong. In any way disregarding this there are several more problems:

You seem to pass in a path variable `pathDate` with which I assume you need to have to do your search. This is never used in the body of the method. Instead you create (in a wrong way) a new variable named `convertDate`. Which you proceed to convert over to a string for no apparent reason and usage.

You then proceed to create a new variable named `date` which you attempt to initialize using the `strDate` variable. All these actions are fundamentally wrong. Also your conversion from String to date is also wrong (hence why you get the IllegalArgumentException).

You should not be using the parent class (`DateFormat`) to perform date conversion but rather you need to perform the conversion using some implementation of it (`DateFormat` is abstract and a direct implementation is the `SimpleDateFormat`).

Based on the above, you should do the following:

- Grab the date from the path variable.
- Use SimpleDateFormat to convert over to a date object (alternatively
  you can use Java 8's LocalDate API)
- Then pass this date to your service method that will fetch the
  results from the repository.

Also a few more notes. There is no need to do this:

`Optional<List<Product>> optional = Optional.of(dateofPurchaseList);`

Assuming that your service method returns either a list of products or an empty list if none are found, the subsequent `dateofPurchaseList` will never be null. Wrapping this into an optional using the `of` static creator (which assumes non-nullnes)
is wrong. You should simple invoke `List#isEmpty` to just check whether the returned list is empty or contains any values.

Comment: Thanks you finding my mistake I will correct this are mistake @Aris

Answer (score 0):

Use this in repository interface

```
@Query("select e from Entity where e.dateOfPurchase like %:dateOfPurchase%")
List<Entity> findByDateOfPurchase(@Param("dateOfPurchase ")String dateOfPurchase );
```