# Spring boot API call with multiple @RequestParam

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, curl, https

I need to find the entries between a date range and would like to make a GET call in the Spring Boot API as follow,

```
$ curl -X GET http://localhost:8080/api/v1/appointments/findWithRange?start=2018-10-01&end=2018-10-15
```

I write the GET call,

```
@GetMapping("/findWithRange")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Appointment>> findAllWithCreationRange(@RequestParam("start")  Date start, @RequestParam("end") Date end) {

        List<Appointment> appointments = service.findAllWithCreationRange(start, end);

        if (Objects.isNull(appointments)) {
            ResponseEntity.badRequest().build();
        }

        return ResponseEntity.ok(appointments);
    }
```

I get the return response,

```
{"timestamp":"2019-02-10T07:58:22.151+0000","status":400,"error":"Bad Request","message":"Required Date parameter 'end' is not present","path":"/api/v1/appointments/findWithRange"}
```

How do I write the call properly? It seems I was not been able to debug as the breakpoints don't catch.

Comment: Are you making sure to quote your `&` from your shell?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Does the shell instantly return before you get the curl output and print something like `[1] 12345`?

Comment: Yes, I just find the API is good and works properly in the Chrome. The issue is only in the terminal.

Comment: You need to learn about the subject *shell quoting*, which is your problem here.

Comment: Thank you so much - you provided the hint to solve the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is very simple - in your call

```
$ curl -X GET http://localhost:8080/api/v1/appointments/findWithRange?start=2018-10-01&end=2018-10-15
```

`&` sign tell operation system '*run `curl -X GET http://localhost:8080/api/v1/appointments/findWithRange?start=2018-10-01` in background*'. This is a reason why `end` date is undefined.

Just surround your URL in double quotes:

```
$ curl -X GET "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/appointments/findWithRange?start=2018-10-01&end=2018-10-15"
```

Comment: Yes, simple but took me like 1.5 hours to try various options and read all the code until I put the same command in the Chrome (which worked) :|

Comment: @Arefe In the future, pay close attention to your output. In this case, `curl -X` would have shown you that it was only passing the first request parameter, which would have been a big hint.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to receive parameter as date then there need to define pattern.
Try with this:

```
@GetMapping("/findWithRange")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Appointment>> findAllWithCreationRange(@RequestParam("start") @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd") Date start, @RequestParam("end") @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd") Date end) {

        List<Appointment> appointments = service.findAllWithCreationRange(start, end);

        if (Objects.isNull(appointments)) {
            ResponseEntity.badRequest().build();
        }

        return ResponseEntity.ok(appointments);
    }
```

If you want to recevie sql.Date then need to use custom deserializer. Try with this:

```
@GetMapping("/findWithRange")
        public ResponseEntity<List<Appointment>> findAllWithCreationRange(@RequestParam("start") @JsonDeserialize(using = SqlDateConverter.class) Date start, @RequestParam("end") @JsonDeserialize(using = SqlDateConverter.class) Date end) {

            List<Appointment> appointments = service.findAllWithCreationRange(start, end);

            if (Objects.isNull(appointments)) {
                ResponseEntity.badRequest().build();
            }

            return ResponseEntity.ok(appointments);
        }
```

Sql date converter:

```
public class SqlDateConverter extends JsonDeserializer<Date> {

    @Override
    public Date deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        return Date.valueOf(p.getText());
    }
}
```

If you want to deserialize sql.Date globally then try with add this bean only:

```
@Bean
    public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder configureObjectMapper() {
        Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder = new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder();
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
        module.addDeserializer(Date.class,new SqlDateConverter());
        objectMapper.registerModule(module);
        builder.configure(objectMapper);
        return builder;
    }
```

Comment: Yes, I have tried it after checking the other answer and this doesn't solve the issue, unfortunately.

Comment: try with this deserializer

Answer (score 1):

You should specify the @DateTimeFormat

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15164864/how-to-accept-date-params-in-a-get-request-to-spring-mvc-controller) you can find more details