# JSON : The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, json

I have the following call

```
$.getJSON("/svrBooking/json/getEmployeesByManager",{
            manager: "Paul Walker",
            endDate: endDate, --> "Thu May 28 16:52:25 BST 2015"
            startDate: startDate, --> "Thu Apr 30 16:52:25 BST 2015"
            ajax: 'true'
            }, function (result) {...});
```

This is calling the following Java code

```
@RequestMapping(value="/getEmployeesByManager" , method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody ReservationsCount
    getEmployeesByManager(Model model,@RequestParam String manager,@RequestParam Date startDate, @RequestParam Date endDate) throws ParseException{...}
```

I am getting the following error

```
GET 'http://localhost:8080/svrBooking/json/getEmployeesByManager?manager=Paul+Walker&endDate=Thu+May+28+16%3A52%3A25+BST+2015&startDate=Thu+Apr+30+16%3A52%3A25+BST+2015&ajax=true'   400 bad request
```

the response says

```
The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.
```

This only started happening when i passed in the Date objects to the getJSON call. If i change the dates to strings everything works fine. Does anyone know what is going on here?

Comment: Different implementations of Date represent date and time differently... You can try http://www.joda.org/joda-time/ jodaTime... Otherwise parse the String to a Date...

Comment: but i already have the startDate and endDate to a Date (e.g. startDate = new Date();) so it should not be a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14766818/passing-date-to-request-param-in-spring-mvc) SO question.
Spring does not know how to parse Date parameters. You have to add the `@DateTimeFormat` annotation after `@RequestParam` to tell Spring which format to expect. For instance:

```
@RequestParam @DateTimeFormat("MMddyyyy") Date startDate
```

In your Javascript API call you must then pass the date in the format you specified.

You should also be able to use the ISO format (I have not tested it) as:

```
@RequestParam @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME) Date startDate
```

Then in your Javascript API call you should format the dates using `toISOString`:

```
$.getJSON("/svrBooking/json/getEmployeesByManager",{
            manager: "Paul Walker",
            endDate: endDate.toISOString(), --> "2015-06-26T08:38:26.175Z"
            startDate: startDate.toISOString(), --> "2015-06-26T08:38:45.304Z"
            ajax: 'true'
            }, function (result) {...});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using surrounding the data *variables* by quotes like so:

```
$.getJSON("/svrBooking/json/getEmployeesByManager",{
            "manager": "Paul Walker",
            "endDate": endDate,
            "startDate": startDate,
            "ajax": 'true'
            }, function (result) {...});
```